# Using Spring Mono and Hibernate initialize not working

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-webflux

I've read many answers here on stackoverflow but still haven't found the best solution to load lazy entities with Spring Mono and JPA/Hibernate.

I can fix it easily by eager fetching but I think that is not the best solution.

My problem now is that I cannot have Hibernate.initialize working either and am looking for a solution. My use case is very simple:

```
@Transactional
public Mono<User> getUserById(String id) {

    log.debug("Get user by {}", id);

    return Mono
            .justOrEmpty(userRepository.findById(id))
            .map(user -> {
                Hibernate.initialize(user.getCustomer().get());
                Hibernate.initialize(user.getCustomer().map(Customer::getCustomerSettings).get());
                return user;
            });
}
```

The thing is that the Customer is an optional so I don't know if that has any impact on it. 
I have tested with and without transactional, with and without .get(), and don't have many more ideas of how to solve this the correct way at the moment.

Always get this error:

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy [com.example.project.customer.model.Customer#692e8725-a5fa-4c87-ac2d-b382b1c6bfbc] - no Session
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The session is already closed after the `findById` wrapping this in a transaction won't work as JPA simply doesn't support reactive. Instead put this in a single method and do all the actions at once. However you are probably better of by writing a specialized query which enables eager fetch for this use case.

Comment: I understand that JPA doesn't support reactive but in this scenario I am not even putting the findById in a separate thread, so I was hoping it was still called in the same context and the transaction was still open. Isn't that the case? Otherwise I can always create a specialized query, I just don't understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes you are. It is separated from the `map` the `map` is a different thread, every function in your reactive pipeline is, possibly, called in a different thread.

Comment: You can't use @Transactional annotation, because it based on ThreadLocal. You have to manage your transaction manually.

Comment: I have printed in the logs the thread Id before the mono, inside the map and after that and it is always the same thread. I believe it would only be a different thread if I would do a defer and subscribeOn. I have removed the Transactional because it is doing nothing but I still don't understand why if we are in the same thread!

Comment: @talkshowhost because reactive is thread agnostic meaning that any thread can do anything. Just because it is the same thread when you do the call, does not guarantee that when you have 500 requests that it will be the same thread. Just because ANY thread can take care of anything, doesnt mean that any thread MUST.  At the time you make a request it is easier for the server to use the same thread, ecause there is no other work being done at the time.